Как добавить в метке в Конструкторе карт свой профиль
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть информацию по созданию в конструкторе карт профиля собственной компании при нажатии на метку.
Если задать вопрос проще, как добавить профиль яндекс карт в описание метки.
Пример, что хотим создать по своей компании.
Заранее всем спасибо.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Спасибо за оперативный отклик. Ответ на свой вопрос нашел. Такой вид метки создается автоматически в профиле Яндекс.Бизнес после создания личного кабинета. Там же есть ссылка для вставки карты на сайт. Еще раз спасибо.

Такую карту для сайта не создать в Конструкторе. Это задача для Виджета — простого инструмента, который позволяет получить интерактивную карту или отзывы для вашего проекта. Вы можете найти на Яндекс Картах организацию или построить маршрут, а затем получить код для вставки на сайт по клику на кнопку «Поделиться».

Спасибо за оперативный отклик. Ответ на свой вопрос нашел. Такой вид метки создается автоматически в профиле Яндекс.Бизнес после создания личного кабинета. Там же есть ссылка для вставки карты на сайт.
